# Symfony 5 + Webpack Encore + Datatables: buttons not being displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, datatables

This is my second failed attempt to use a library to export a simple table to any kind of document (Excel, PDF, etc.).

This time I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). The table is being displayed and everything seems good, but no button for exporting, copying or anything is displayed.

[image]

As you can see there are no export buttons anywhere. There are also no warnings or errors in the developer console.

These are the steps I followed in order to use DataTables in my Symfony 5 project:

1. Add the CDN links to the base template from the [download page](https://datatables.net/download/index) with the following options:

   - **Styling Framework**: Bootstrap 4
   - **Packages**:

     - DataTables
   - **Extensions**:

     - Buttons, HTML5 Export, JSZip, pdfmake
     - Print view
     - Responsive
2. Instantiate the DataTable to create the table. This is how the final JS looks like in the developer console:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/inventory_items.json",
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        buttons: ['excel'],
        columns: [{
                data: 'center.name',
                title: 'Centro',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'program.name',
                title: 'Programa',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'description',
                title: 'Descripción',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'comment',
                title: 'Comentario',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'item_condition',
                title: 'Condición',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'age',
                title: 'Antigüedad',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'purchase_price',
                title: 'Precio de compra',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'purchase_currency',
                title: 'Moneda de compra',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'sn',
                title: 'S/N',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'physical_location',
                title: 'Ubicación Física',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                title: 'Fecha',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'ref',
                title: 'Documento de referencia',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'status',
                title: 'Estado',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'os',
                title: 'Sistema Operativo',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'cpu',
                title: 'Procesador',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'type',
                title: 'Tipo de procesador',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'hdd',
                title: 'Disco duro',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'ram',
                title: 'Memoria RAM',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            }
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
            url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
    })
})
```

This is how my Twig table base template looks like:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% set bodyTitle %}
    {% block setBodyTitle %}{% endblock %}
{% endset %}

{% block title %}
    {{ parent() }} | {{ bodyTitle }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container{% block fluid%}{% endblock%} mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>{{ bodyTitle }} <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% block bodyCreateUrl %}{% endblock %}">➕</a></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <table class="table"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-colvis-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/cr-1.5.2/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-colvis-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/sp-1.1.1/datatables.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.table').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/{% block jsApi %}{% endblock %}.json",
                    dataSrc: ''
                },
                buttons: [ 'excel' ],
                columns: [{% block jsTableColumns %}{% endblock %}],
                responsive: true,
                language: {
                    url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Despite everything I did was on my Symfony project I have tried to replicate the frontend on a snippet:

```js
var fakeApiData = [{
    id: 1,
    program: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Some place'
    },
    description: 'fgdfg',
    comment: 'dfgdfg',
    item_condition: 'New',
    location: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Some place'
    },
    fund_source: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Donation'
    },
    age: '1',
    purchase_price: 1200,
    purchase_currency: 'US$',
    physical_location: 'Somewhere',
    date: '2020-07-05T00:00:00+02:00',
    status: 'ok',
    os: 'Windows 10',
    ram: 4,
    cpu: 'I3 3.2GHz',
    type: 'x64',
    hdd: '320',
    center: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Some place'
    }
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').DataTable({
        data: fakeApiData,
        buttons: ['excel', 'copy' ],
        columns: [{
                data: 'center.name',
                title: 'Centro',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'program.name',
                title: 'Programa',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'description',
                title: 'Descripción',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'comment',
                title: 'Comentario',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'item_condition',
                title: 'Condición',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'age',
                title: 'Antigüedad',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'purchase_price',
                title: 'Precio de compra',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'purchase_currency',
                title: 'Moneda de compra',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'sn',
                title: 'S/N',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'physical_location',
                title: 'Ubicación Física',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                title: 'Fecha',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'ref',
                title: 'Documento de referencia',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'status',
                title: 'Estado',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'os',
                title: 'Sistema Operativo',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'cpu',
                title: 'Procesador',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'type',
                title: 'Tipo de procesador',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'hdd',
                title: 'Disco duro',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            },
            {
                data: 'ram',
                title: 'Memoria RAM',
                defaultContent: 'N/A',
            }
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
            url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.21/b-1.6.2/b-html5-1.6.2/b-print-1.6.2/r-2.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <table class="table"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet, the left button that expands information regarding "Centro" column is not present in my table, as you can appreciate...

I have changed DataTables option `ajax` for `data` to "call" some fake data (similar to my server) in order to make a test.

But anyway, here the export buttons are not being displayed either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating DataTables twice it has to be instantiated only once

add this code inside your datatables function it will allow you to copy/csv/pdf...

```
$('.table').DataTable({
    dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: {
        name: 'primary',
       buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf' ]
        }}       
    );
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/679oaLwx/) of a working example

Comment: Well, that `dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',` worked great. Thank you.

Comment: @Maramal - For reference: See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) for an explanation of the `dom` option. That `B` is for "button initialization".

Comment: @Maramal -  Also, I suggest you should change your language URL so that it includes the protocol: `https:`. See [this article](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) for more info on that - but basically, skipping the protocol is no longer recommended.